# BinarySearchTree implementation

Tags: java, class, interface, binary-search-tree, implementation

I want to implement the BinarySearchTree and I've come that far at the moment:

My question is how I should complete the second file.

Here is the first file:

```
package u7a3;

/**
 * generic binary search-tree with integer keys.
 * Empty trees are encoded as null references.
 *
 * @param <T> The type of the things which are managed in the binary
 * search tree
 */

public class BinarySearchTree<T> {
    /**
     * The key by which the thing is refered to. Must be unique.
     */
    public int key;

    /**
     * The thing itself.
     */
    public T thing;

    /**
     * The left sub-tree
     */
    public BinarySearchTree<T> left;

    /**
     * The right sub-tree
     */
    public BinarySearchTree<T> right;

    /**
     * Create a new binary search tree without children.
     * @param key the key by which the thing is refered to
     * @param thing the new thing
     */
    public BinarySearchTree(int key, T thing)
    {
        this.key = key;
        this.thing = thing;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }

    /**
     * Create a new binary search tree
     * @param key the key by which the thing is refered to
     * @param thing the thing which is managed by the new binary search tree
     * @param left the left sub-tree of the new binary search tree
     * @param right the right sub-tree of the new binary search tree
     */
    public BinarySearchTree(int key, T thing, BinarySearchTree<T> left, BinarySearchTree<T> right)
    {
        this.key = key;
        this.thing = thing;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
}
```

The second file is where I still have to do edit respectively complete:

```
package u7a3;

import java.util.ArrayList;

class BinarySearchTreeUtils<T> implements IBinarySearchTreeUtils<T> {

    public int key;

    public T thing;

    public BinarySearchTree<T> left;

    public BinarySearchTree<T> right;

    public BinarySearchTreeUtils()
    {
        this.key = key;
        this.thing = thing;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }

    public int height(BinarySearchTree<T> tree) //Need help
    {
        //if (tree.left == null || tree.right == null) return 0;
        /*else if (tree.left == null) return height(tree.right);
        else if (tree.right == null) return height(tree.left);
        else*/ return 0;
    }

    public boolean isLeaf(BinarySearchTree<T> tree)
    {
        return tree.left == null && tree.right == null;
    }

    public boolean hasOneChild(BinarySearchTree<T> tree) //Correct?
    {
        //return (isLeaf(tree.left) == true || isLeaf(tree.right) == true) && (tree.left == null || tree.right == null);
        return isLeaf(tree.left) == true && tree.right == null || isLeaf(tree.right) == true && tree.left == null;
    }

    public ArrayList<T> preOrder(BinarySearchTree<T> tree) //Need help
    {
        return new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    public ArrayList<T> inOrder(BinarySearchTree<T> tree) //Need help
    {
        return new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    public ArrayList<T> postOrder(BinarySearchTree<T> tree) //Need help
    {
        return new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    public BinarySearchTree<T> insert(BinarySearchTree<T> tree, int key, T thing) //Need help
    {
        return new BinarySearchTree(0, this);
    }

    public T find(BinarySearchTree<T> tree, int key) //Need help
    {
        BinarySearchTree<T> treeleft = tree.left;
        BinarySearchTree<T> treeright = tree.right;
        if (isLeaf(tree) == true && tree.key != key) return null;
        //else if((treeleft.key) >= key) return find(tree.left, key);
        //else if((treeright.key) <= key) return find(tree.right, key);
        //else if (treeleft.key == key) return treeleft.thing;
        //else if (treeright.key == key) return treeright.thing;
        //else*/ //return tree.thing;
        else return tree.thing;
    }

    public BinarySearchTree<T> remove(BinarySearchTree<T> tree, int key) //Need help
    {
        return new BinarySearchTree(0, this);
    }
}
```

Here is the third file:

```
package u7a3;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Utility functions for binary search trees containing generic things
 * 
 * @param <T>
 *            The type of the things which are managed in the binary search tree
 */
public interface IBinarySearchTreeUtils<T> {
    /**
     * Determines the height of a tree.
     * 
     * The empty tree has height zero. The tree consisting only of the root has
     * height one.
     * 
     * @param tree
     *            the tree in question
     * @return the height of the given tree
     */
    public int height(BinarySearchTree<T> tree);

    /**
     * Checks if a tree is actually a leaf node.
     * 
     * A tree is a leave node if and only if (iff) it has no children.
     * 
     * @param tree
     *            the tree in question. May not be null.
     * @return true iff the given tree is a leaf node.
     */
    public boolean isLeaf(BinarySearchTree<T> tree);

    /**
     * Checks if a tree has only one child.
     * 
     * @param tree
     *            the tree in question
     * @return true iff the given tree has only one child.
     */
    public boolean hasOneChild(BinarySearchTree<T> tree);

    /**
     * Returns the things of a tree in pre-order.
     * 
     * @param tree
     *            the tree containing the things
     * @return an ArrayList of the things of the given tree, sorted in pre-order.
     */
    public ArrayList<T> preOrder(BinarySearchTree<T> tree);

    /**
     * Returns the things of a tree in in-order.
     * 
     * @param tree
     *            the tree containing the things
     * @return an ArrayList of the things of the given tree, sorted in in-order.
     */
    public ArrayList<T> inOrder(BinarySearchTree<T> tree);

    /**
     * Returns the things of a tree in post-order.
     * 
     * @param tree
     *            the tree containing the things
     * @return an ArrayList of the things of the given tree, sorted in post-order.
     */
    public ArrayList<T> postOrder(BinarySearchTree<T> tree);

    /**
     * Inserts an thing into a tree
     * 
     * If an thing with the given key already exists in the tree it is
     * overwritten.
     * 
     * @param tree
     *            the tree into which the thing is inserted. After the call this
     *            tree should not be used any more. Use the returned tree
     *            instead.
     * @param key
     *            the key of the thing
     * @param thing
     *            the thing which is inserted into the tree
     * @return a new tree with the given thing inserted.
     */
    public BinarySearchTree<T> insert(BinarySearchTree<T> tree, int key, T thing);

    /**
     * Finds an thing in a tree.
     * 
     * @param tree
     *            the tree in which the thing is searched for.
     * @param key
     *            the key of the thing which is searched
     * @return the thing if it exists in the tree, and null otherwise.
     */
    public T find(BinarySearchTree<T> tree, int key);

    /**
     * Removes a thing from a tree.
     * 
     * If the thing is in a leaf node this node is simply removed
     * If the thing is in node with one child this node is replaced by its child.
     * Otherwise the removed node is replaced by the smallest node of its right subtree.
     * 
     * @param tree
     *            the tree from which the thing is removed. After this call this
     *            tree should not be used any more. Use the returned tree
     *            instead.
     * @param key
     *            the key of the thing
     * @return either a new tree with the given thing removed or the simply the
     *         given tree if the thing could not be found.
     */
    public BinarySearchTree<T> remove(BinarySearchTree<T> tree, int key);
}
```

The fourth file is the main class, but it isn't important for my problem:

```
/**
 * Main class of the Java program. 
 * 
 */
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("-- Binary Search --");
        /* you can make function calls from here*/
    }
}
```

Here is the fifth and last file which should be okay like this:

```
package u7a3;

public class UtilsFactory {
    public static IBinarySearchTreeUtils<String> create()
    {
        // TODO 
        return new BinarySearchTreeUtils();
    }
}
```

Comment: And your question is....?

Comment: I just added it.

Comment: Too unspecific. What exactly is missing/not working? What are the concepts you are struggling with? Please be as precise as possible.

Comment: Okay, then I put comments in my code of what I mean. I write either "//Need help" or "//Correct?" in the code.

Comment: Is this not enough?

Comment: I need to do the methods of BinarySearchUtils.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method hasOneChild should be like this:

```
public boolean hasOneChild(BinarySearchTree<T> tree)
    {
        return tree.left != null && tree.right == null || tree.left != null && tree.left == null;
    }
```